# How do call my function properly while still keeping the values of the variables used in the function?

Tags: arrays, c, function

My code has multiple function and in one function, a value is given to `playerNum` based on user input. Another function gives values to an array, `cardDeck[DECK]` (`DECK` is a constant defined as `52`).

I want a function called `deal` to use these two variables as parameters, but it resets them meaning they are both equal to zero.

Here is the minimal reproducible example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int players(int playerNum);
int cards(int cardDeck[4]);
int deal (int *cardDeck[4], int *playerNum);

int main() {
    int playerNum;
    int cardDeck[4];

    players(playerNum);

    cards(cardDeck);

    deal(&cardDeck, &playerNum);
    return 0;
}
int players(int playerNum){
    playerNum = 10;
    printf("%d", playerNum);
    return playerNum;
}
int cards(int cardDeck[4]){
    cardDeck[0] = 1;
    cardDeck[1] = 2;
    cardDeck[2] = 3;
    cardDeck[3] = 4;
    return *cardDeck;
}
int deal (int *cardDeck[4], int *playerNum){
    printf("%d", *playerNum);
    return 1;
}
```

The code is not finished, but here it is so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DECK 52

int setUpDeck (int cardDeck[DECK]);
int shuffleDeck (int cardDeck[DECK]);
int howToPlay (char instructions[200]);
int gameStyle(char gamePlay, int playerNum);
int deal(int *cardDeck[DECK], int *playerNum);
int playersMode(int cardDeck[DECK]);
int computerMode(int cardDeck[DECK]);
int endOfGame (int playerDeck);
int main() {
    //declare and initilaize
    int cardDeck[DECK] = {0, 0, 0};
    char instructions[200];
    char gamePlay;
    int playerNum;
    bool play = true;
    bool computer;
    bool players;
    int noMoreCards = 0;
    int placeholder[5];

    //call function setUpDeck
    setUpDeck(cardDeck);

    while (play == true){
        //call the function shuffleDeck
        shuffleDeck(cardDeck);
        
        //call function howToPlay
        howToPlay(instructions);
       
        //Input
        //call function gameStyle
        gameStyle(gamePlay, playerNum);
    
        //call function deal
        deal(&cardDeck[DECK], &playerNum);

        //Gameplay
        if(computer == true){
            computerMode(cardDeck);
        }
        else{
            playersMode(cardDeck);            
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//This function reads the deck text file into the cardEck array
int setUpDeck(int cardDeck[DECK]){
    //file pointer and open file for reading
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("deck.txt", "r");

    //error checking
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open deck.txt.");
        return 1;
    }

    //read in the values of the cards
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &cardDeck[i]);
    }

    //close file 
    fclose(fptr);
    return cardDeck[DECK];
}

//This function shuffles the cardDeck array
int shuffleDeck (int cardDeck[DECK]){
    
   for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        int placeHolder = 0;
        int j = rand() % 51;
        placeHolder = cardDeck[i];
        cardDeck[i] = cardDeck[j];
        cardDeck[j] = placeHolder;
   }
    
    return cardDeck[DECK];
}

//This function reads the instructions text file and prints it out
int howToPlay (char instructions[200]){
    //file pointer and open file for reading
    FILE *rules;
    rules = fopen("instructions.txt", "r");

    //error checking
    if (rules == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open instructions.txt.");
        return 1;
    }

    //read instructions from text file
    //and print them to the screen
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        fgets(instructions, 200, rules);
        printf("%s", instructions);
    }

     //close file 
    fclose(rules);
    return 1;
}

//This function asks players what game Style they want and how many players they want
int gameStyle(char gamePlay, int playerNum){
    //declare and initilaize variables
     bool players = false;
     bool computer = false;
   
    //Ask user input about game play
    while(computer == false && players == false){
        printf("\n\nPlease select a Game play option: Player vs Player(p) or Player vs Computer(c): ");
        scanf(" %c", &gamePlay);
        gamePlay = tolower(gamePlay);
        switch(gamePlay){
            case 'p': players = true;
                    break;
            case 'c': computer = true;
                    break;
            default: printf("\nError: not a Game Play option.");
                    break;
        }
    }

    //Ask user input about number of players
    if(players == true){
        printf("\nHow many players would you like? Pick a number from 2-6:");
        scanf("%d", &playerNum);
    }
    else if (players == false){
        playerNum = 1;
    }
    printf("%d", playerNum);
    return playerNum;
}
//This function creates the player arrays and deals two cards to each deck
int deal(int *cardDeck[DECK], int *playerNum){
    //declare and initialize variables
    int deckCardNum = 0;
    int playerCards[*playerNum][10];
    bool computer;
    int compCards[10];

    printf("%d", *playerNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < *playerNum; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            playerCards[i][j] = *cardDeck[deckCardNum];
            deckCardNum = deckCardNum + 1;
        }
    }
    if(computer == true){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            compCards[j] = *cardDeck[deckCardNum];
            deckCardNum = deckCardNum + 1;
    }
    }
    return 1;
}
//This function handles gamplay(asking players if they want another card) for the player vs player mode
int playersMode(int cardDeck[DECK]){
    //declare and initialize variables
    char giveCard;
    int deckCardNum = 0;
    int playerNum;
     int cardNum[playerNum];
    int playerDeck[playerNum][10];
    int sum = 0;
    int noMoreCards = 0; //this will stop the game if all the players don't want anymore cards
    
    while (noMoreCards < playerNum){
        for(int i = 0; i <= playerNum; i++){
            cardNum[i] = 2;
            for (int k = 0; k < DECK; k++){
                sum = sum + playerDeck[i][k];
            }
            printf("\n\nPlayer %d: Your total is %d. Would you like another card?(y/n)", i + 1, sum);
            while(deckCardNum == 0 || noMoreCards == 0){
                scanf("%s", &giveCard);
                giveCard = tolower(giveCard);
                switch(giveCard){ 
                    case 'y':playerDeck[i][cardNum[i]] = cardDeck[deckCardNum];
                            deckCardNum = deckCardNum + 1;
                            break;
                    case 'n':noMoreCards = noMoreCards + 1;
                            break;
                    default:printf("Error: Enter y/n");
                            break;
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < DECK; k++){
                    sum = sum + playerDeck[i][k];
                }
                if(sum > 21 && sum != 27){
                    printf("Player %d has a total of %d, and is disqualified", i + 1,sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return 1;
}
//this function handles the gamplay(asking players if they want another card)for the player vs computer mode
int computerMode(int cardDeck[DECK]){

    return 1;
}
//This counts everyone's points at the end of the game and announces the winner
int endOfGame (int playerDeck){

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the minimal reproducible example

Your minimal reproducible example is really meaningless.

`players(playerNum);`

```
int players(int playerNum){
    playerNum = 10;
    printf("%d", playerNum);
    return playerNum;
}
```

The important thing here is `playerNum = 10;` you are doing inside function `players` is local to that function itself, those changes cannot be seen by the caller function unless you collect it.

Your call `players(playerNum);` should actually be like `playerNum = players(playerNum);`

Your `players` function if all it does is `playerNum = 10;` and return that value, there is no use of it really, you could have just used `playerNum = 10;` in `main` itself.

Your `cards` function the call is correct, but in definition no need of using `return *cardDeck;`(this will return only `cardDeck[0]`), as `cardDeck` is an array, when you pass array as an argument in this case the address is passed and changes will be reflected inside the caller function.

Your `cards` function can be written as below:

```
void cards(int cardDeck[4]){
    cardDeck[0] = 1;
    cardDeck[1] = 2;
    cardDeck[2] = 3;
    cardDeck[3] = 4;
}
```